# Hacer que el voto de cierre "la pregunta no está en español" aparezca como comentario

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-postergado, comentarios, votos-de-cierre

No sé si es posible, pero creo que estaría bien que si, al emitirse un voto de cierre por "La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial del sitio es español", ya le apareciera como comentario a la pregunta de forma similar a como lo hace cuando se vota el cierre por duplicado.

De esta forma la persona que hace la pregunta tiene ya automáticamente el feedback (perdón, realimentación :-)) para editar la pregunta.

Comment: Diría que no es posible. Las razones de cierre como "No relacionado porque..." no generan un comentario automático. Diría que en inglés tampoco lo hace.

Comment: Voy a comentarle esto al equipo de desarrolladores para ver si se puede hacer.  No hago promesas, veamos que se puede hacer. :)

Comment: Me parece que sería de gran ayuda, buena idea. Algo similar se pidió hace cinco años en MetaSE y ningún miembro de SE se ha manifestado sobre ello: [Auto Comment for Off Topic -> Minimal Understanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188821/auto-comment-for-off-topic-minimal-understanding). También veo [Add automatic comments for every closure reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186307/add-automatic-comments-for-every-closure-reason), más genérica.

Comment: @Juan ¿sigues de CM? Pensé que eataba Nicolas ya.

Comment: @fedorqui está Nicolas como CM. En principio si no lo he entendido yo mal, Juan está por encima :)

Comment: @Pikoh yo en Meta.SE entendí que Juan cambiaba de sección y haría de CM de apoyo de otros sitios de SE

Comment: @fedorqui es posible, como digo es lo que yo entendí. Pero si te puedo confirmar que Nicolas está ejerciendo efectivamente como CM (por ejemplo, en el tema del manifiesto y cuando se ha ofrecido a modificar razones de cierre). Por el chat ha entrado varias veces ofreciéndose para lo que necesitemos.

Comment: @fedorqui Seguiré participando aquí en varias formas pero Nicolas es el encargado y yo su supervisor.

Comment: @JuanM ¿Cuándo deberemos sincronizar los temas aquí discutidos con [meta.se]? ¿Podemos dar por sentado que este ya no es necesario sincronizarlo con [meta.se] dado que has declarado tomar cartas en este asunto? :)

Comment: @Rubén Sí, efectivamente.  Si he comentado en algo aquí, dejémoslo tal y como esta para no crear dos fuentes de información.  Creo que esto sucederá solamente en ocasiones escasas.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Por ahora no será posible añadir esta función.  Sigamos tratando con este tipo de preguntas de la misma manera - usando en voto de cierre y dejando el comentario manualmente.

Si es algo urgente, comuniquemoslo con uno de los moderadores.

Comment: Voto negativo. Me extraña que algo así no sea implementable. Siempre es algo urgente y "obligar" a que los otros usuarios pongan un comentario o reportar parece mucho más costoso que hacer un trogger automático que, por ejemplo, ya está para las duplicadas.

Comment: No es qué no sea implementable, los recursos de los devs no permite hacer este cambio por ahora. Lo tengo anotado, voy a intentar volver a introducir esto después de que pase un tiempo.

Comment: Es que siempre topamos con la misma piedra. Supuestamente los SOxx son utilísimos e importantísimos, pero en la práctica hace siglos que no se hace nada por ellos que no sean anuncios grandilocuentes. El único dev puesto aquí es g3rv4 y en su tiempo libre. Duele la inconsistencia del mensaje de SE.

Answer (score -2):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), we don't have immediate plans to work on this request. We'll revisit it at a later date and provide more details here when it has been prioritized and/or completed.

---

**Traducción**

Según nuestra [hoja de ruta actual](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), no tenemos planes inmediatos para trabajar en esta solicitud. Lo revisaremos en una fecha posterior y proporcionaremos más detalles aquí cuando haya sido priorizado y/o completado.