# Los 3 votos para el cierre causan un problema si no se dejan comentarios

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Estoy notando que con los 3 votos para el cierre, las preguntas de mala calidad fluyen a ser cerradas mas rápidamente.

Sin embargo, también estoy notando que varios usuarios nuevos que obtuvieron privilegios de cierre, están cerrando las preguntas mas rápidamente, pero no están comentando sobre los problemas que tienen las preguntas.

Esta bien que al usuario que hizo la pregunta se le deja un aviso, con el motivo que causo el cierre de la pregunta.

Algunos motivos, son obvios, como que la pregunta esta en otro idioma. Pero noto que con los otros motivos, no se le esta dejando al usuario que pregunto una explicación mas clara de que se necesita para que la pregunta pueda ser mejorada.

Inclusive, algunos cierres parecen apurados y con poco sentido. Si los 3 votos causan esto, entonces es algo que va en contra de lo que necesita el sitio.

Una cosa es cerrar preguntas en otro idioma, o ejercicios por ser resueltos, o preguntas que casi son solo una pregunta sin nada de código ni explicación. Y otra muy diferente es una pregunta completa mal explicada (que seguro puede ser mejorada) o una pregunta que parece ambigua pero para la cual se puede pedir explicaciones antes de hacer un cierre apurado.

Sin embargo, el primer tipo de preguntas igual merece una explicación de porque se pide el cierre de la misma...

Como lo aclaro siempre, los privilegios implican también tomarse el tiempo para hacerlos valer como corresponde. El sitio nos permite tomar a los moderadores electos acciones sobre quienes ejercen mal esos privilegios.

Les pido a todos, que si van a revisar colas, lo hagan muy a conciencia y tomando el tiempo necesario para revisar todos los aspectos. Y que ante la duda, no duden en apretar el botón omitir, que esta para cuando uno no puede tomar una decisión a conciencia y con el tiempo suficiente.

Me encantaría tener otros puntos de vista respecto a esto.

Comment: A veces dejo un comentario a mis votos de cierre, pero sólo es por frustración por la mala calidad de las preguntas. Según mis cálculos, el 90% de las preguntas Python son de personas a quienes no le será de utilidad ningún comentario, gente que viene a que le hagan la tarea y le resuelvan el problema rápido para pasar a otra cosa.

Comment: A mí me sirvió la recomendación que dieron alguna vez, de tener plantillas de mensajes para cada caso.

Comment: *Si los 3 votos causan esto, entonces es algo que va en contra de lo que necesita el sitio* -> Sinceramente, @gbianchi, yo he dejado de poner comentarios de por qué había votado para cerrar tras sufrir un montón de ataques de gente engreída, con malas pulgas y muy mala educación que no saben tomarse a bien una crítica constructiva. Cuando estás intentando ayudar a alguien a que pueda encontrar respuesta y te insultan, al final acabas perdiendo las ganas de ayudar a nadie :)

Comment: Como todos @Benito-B, pero esa gente termina penalizada... y no hagas caso a lo que te dice alguien escudado por el anonimato de internet...

Answer (score 17):

El problema no es de los usuarios que votan para cerrar. El problema es de la plataforma:

Sobre publicaciones en inglés: con la propuesta [Hacer que el voto de cierre “la pregunta no está en español” aparezca como comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3698/83) tendríamos buena tarea ya hecha. Y qué tal si se mejorar lo implementado en su día en [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83).

Insisto, el problema no es de los usuarios, sino de Stack Overflow como empresa que ha decidido no poner recursos en los Stack Overflow internacionales. ¿Cuánto hace que un CM nos trae alguna novedad útil y relevante que no sea una traducción -que hacemos nosotros, dicho sea de paso-?

La plataforma debe mejorar en cuanto a fomentar calidad con pasos muy claros. Si no, estamos obligando a los usuarios con ganas a que repitan una y otra vez lo mismo a un sinnúmero de usuarios que se registran en el sitio sin que se les guíe.

Alguien dijo alguna vez que el problema de la moderación en Stack Overflow es que hay un lago por vaciar y apenas nos dan una cucharilla de café para hacer la tarea. Yo añadiría que nos dan una cucharilla a regañadientes, nos piden que no la usemos demasiado fuerte para no salpicar y nos entretienen mientras tanto con fuegos artificiales.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, y se supone que hay herramientas en curso para eso.. pero en el mientras tanto.. que hacemos? igual, las preguntas en ingles siguen apareciendo...

Comment: @gbianchi ojalá lo supiera, la verdad. Sobre lo de inglés habría que hacer análisis profundo de qué palabras contienen las publicaciones que se acaban formulando y ver cómo mejorar el filtro. Sobre preguntas malas así en general, creo que cerrar más para que los nuevos usuarios que no cumplan un mínimo no puedan preguntar repetidamente.

Comment: Espero no estar fuera de lugar, pero creo que es un tema bastante importante y se esta yendo un poco por la tangente al hablar solo de los temas en otro idioma.

Si es necesario hacer algo por mientras, tratar de siempre poner al menos un comentario antes de votar para cerrar, en mis inicios (no hace mucho) me cerraron muchas preguntas y me quede frustrado sin saber que estaba pasando, lo que va matando (considero) el espiritu pensado para la web.