# Mejora en la descripción en Modal de Report y tooltip

Tags: discusión

Mi sugerencia es mejorar las Descripciones que actualmente se dejan ver en el tooltip de voto negativo y el de reporte de post:

Inclusive a lo mejor mi sugerencia no utilice las palabras adecuadas, si tienen una idea para la redacción no duden en comentarlas.

Textos a ser agregado según esta propuesta:

- tooltip de voto negativo o [en votar negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): ***hacer un comentario al usuario orientándolo sobre los detalles faltantes puede ayudarle a realizar una mejor edición de su post y evitar próximos votos negativos.***
- Interface de voto cierre o [en emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions): ***hacer un comentario al usuario orientándolo sobre el motivo de cierre y los detalles faltantes pueden ayudarle a realizar una mejor edición de su post y agregar informacion importante basada en la experiencia de quien cierra la publicación.***

La ayuda dice lo siguiente:

> ¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto negativo?
> El privilegio de voto positivo viene primero porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. **El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición**.

El Objetivo de este POST es Fomentar el uso de Comentarios descriptivos y objetivos, a lo mejor no tendrá la visibilidad esperada pero es un comienzo.

En este post no se busca distraer ni coartar la capacidad de sufragio de los usuarios con la capacidad de emitir votos; lo que se busca es mejorar la comunicación del usuario y la comunidad.

Reconozco el valor que tiene los votos de negativo como dato estadístico.
y reconozco el valor que tiene los votos de cierre como método de depuración y quilificación de las publicaciones.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con el cambio del segundo cuadro, pero del primero nop. Dejar un comentario no es obligatorio. La definición enese caso es correcta

Comment: @Christian no dice que sea obligatorio, en ninguno. es una mera sugerencia

Comment: @Christian no todos tienen el tiempo o las ganas de dejar un comentario productivo u orientativo ... queda a decisión del usuario ... no es obligatorio XD

Comment: Igual noto que es demasiado texto para una descripción de un voto

Comment: hay otras mas extensa y no hay quejas por la extensión de la descripción ... incluso es la mas corta...

Comment: @Christian me parece que estas buscándole la quinta pata al gato... puedes dar un comentario objetivo por que crees que es mala idea mejorar las descripciones? por que no creo que la cantidad de caracteres sea relevante...

Comment: Nunca dije que sea mala idea mejor la descripción, solo considero innecesario agregarle más texto a una descripción bastante clara. Si deseas ahondar en la forma de como se debe votar y que hacer en esos casos eso debe de explicarse en el recorrido o alguna sección especializada a eso

Comment: ese no es el objetivo, agregar descripción no va a cambiar que el usuario vote o no vote ...

Comment: @Christian has leido lo que dice la ayuda sobre los votos negativos???

Comment: aquí te lo dejo mira: ***¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto negativo?
El privilegio de voto positivo viene primero porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición.***

Comment: cual es tu objetivo? hacer que las personas no voten en contra? promover los comentarios antes que el voto en contra?.

Comment: Como te digo, si quieres concientizar a los usuarios sobre el uso del voto en contra y el potencial de los comentarios. Debes de modificar el articulo de ayuda o añadir en el recorrido algo como: "Si vez una pregunta mal redactada o de baja calidad un comentario ayuda mucho más que un voto negativo. Explica como el autor puede mejorar su publicación y dale chances de obtener su respuesta"

Comment: @Christian ese es el objetivo pero no puedo llegar a el si todos los que tienen derecho a voto asumen que ese es el objetivo del sitio ... si la mayoria se pusiera de acuerdo en que es mejor un comentario para la comunidad  que un voto negativo entonces valdria la pena proponer un cambio en el recorrido de lo contrario no tiene sentido...

Comment: solo para que quede claro. Yo estoy a favor de fomentar el uso de comentarios antes que el voto negativo, solo no estoy de acuerdo a agregar más texto en la **pequeña** descripción que señalas

Comment: @Christian respeto tu opinio pero es o fue mi idea para fomentarlo... no se me ocurre algo que tenga un mejor aceptacion.

Comment: Estoy totalmente en contra de esta propuesta. Los votos son esenciales para mantener es sitio, y deben ser desligados completamente de los comentarios, que como se explica en la ayuda, son simplemente notas temporales. Es decisión de cada usuario comentar o no, y no me parece correcto fomentarlo de ninguna forma

Comment: El texto que propones esta mal escrito y es demasiado largo. Los mensajes deben ser simples y directos:  "Agrega un comentario aclarando que falta."

Answer (score 9):

La propuesta de cambio es incentivar el uso de comentarios como alternativa al voto negativo o de cierre.

Considero que la sugerencia no aplica por los siguientes motivos:

1. **El voto es la pieza central de la moderación del sitio.**

Si leemos la sección del [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) sobre la moderación y reputación y el porqué es importante **votar**, podemos darnos cuenta que el [modelo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) de Stackoverflow en Español se fundamenta sobre un sistema de votos y no de comentarios.

> Los votos son una parte central de nuestro modelo para proporcionar preguntas y respuestas de calidad;
>
> ...
>
> Sólo mediante los votos se consigue que emerja una clase de editores, cerradores y moderadores que ayuden en el funcionamiento y el gobierno del sitio. Votando es como se forma el liderazgo en el sitio.
>
> ... los votos en preguntas y respuestas son el mecanismo *principal* por el cual la comunidad gobierna el sitio en el día a día.
>
> Votar es tan importante que hay una variedad de medallas asociadas a diferentes aspectos de las votaciones – como emitir tu primer voto positivo o negativo, usar todos los votos permitidos en un día, o emitir votos positivos en respuestas de otras personas a preguntas a las que tú mismo has respondido.
>
> Emitir un voto positivo a una pregunta o respuesta señala para resto de la comunidad que una publicación es interesante, el autor ha investigado, y es útil; emitir un voto negativo señala lo contrario: que la publicación contiene información errónea, no hay investigación previa, o no consigue comunicar información. Cuanta más gente vote en una publicación, tanto más seguros pueden estar los futuros visitantes acerca de la calidad de la información contenida en la misma – ¡y por supuesto los votos positivos son una magnífica forma de agradecimiento al autor de la publicación por el tiempo y el esfuerzo dedicados para escribirla!

Hay muchísimas más medallas asociadas a la acción del voto que a la acción del comentario. De hecho, la única medalla que recuerdo haber obtenido por un comentario, no fue por el comentario en sí, sino por la aceptación del mismo que se expresó en votos al comentario.

2. **El voto negativo es un privilegio para usuarios con 125 puntos de reputación o más.**

Un usuario que ha alcanzado este nivel de reputación ya sabe la importancia del voto, por lo cual intentar persuadir a cualquier usuario con este privilegio a que cambie su voto por un comentario es desvirtuar el privilegio mismo.

El sistema de privilegios está diseñado desde sus inicios para dar valor a la participación y moderación del sitio de forma paulatina. Es por ello que con 15 puntos de reputación se puede votar positivo en cualquier publicación, pero dejar comentarios en cualquier publicación sólo es posible con 50 puntos de reputación.

Ahora, si la moderación del sitio se basara en comentarios, ¿porqué los mismos son un privilegio más elevado que los votos positivos?.

Obviamente los votos negativos tienen un componente adicional de confianza por lo cual este privilegio *cuesta más* obtenerlo. Sino, reinaría la anarquía con usuarios que se dedicarían a *trolear* las publicaciones y el sistema de votos.

Por último, muchos de los que colaboramos en el sitio lo hacemos en nuestros momentos *libres*, por lo cual a veces no tenemos el tiempo suficiente para escribir comentarios que muchas veces terminan ignorados por el OP. El voto sigue siendo un reflejo más sincero y real de la calidad de una publicación, el comentario en cambio muchas veces pasa totalmente desapercibido.

El comentario es *opcional* y *no obligatorio*, nunca está pensado como un sustituto del voto. En tu publicación enlazas el texto:

> **¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto negativo?**
>
> El privilegio de voto positivo viene primero porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición.

Pero ese no es el tema principal del texto que explica el [privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) del voto negativo. El tema principal es:

> **¿Qué es votar negativo?**
>
> La emisión de votos negativos, también conocida como "votar en contra", es la forma en la que la comunidad indica qué preguntas y respuestas son menos útiles.
>
> **¿Cuándo debo votar negativo?**
>
> Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás peligrosamente incorrecta.
>
> Tienes un número limitado de votos por día y además votar negativo en una respuesta te cuesta un poco de reputación. Utiliza estos votos de manera sabia.

Entonces, en ningún momento se indica que el *comentario* es *preferible*, sólo se hace la acotación de que existe una *alternativa*. Al contrario de lo que tu propones, el texto que explica el privilegio claramente expone que si lo tienes lo uses, con discreción desde luego.

3. **Cuando se emite un voto de cierre es porque la pregunta lo merece.**

Emitir un voto de cierre (no es lo mismo que votar negativo) es un privilegio que se obtiene al llegar a los 3000 puntos de reputación. Cuando alcanzas este privilegio, ya tienes un recorrido respetable en el sitio y por lo tanto ya sabes (o al menos es lo que se espera) cuáles preguntas son candidatas a cierre por los diferentes motivos explicados en [texto de dicho privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> **¿Qué es el cierre de preguntas?**
>
> El cierre de una pregunta es un proceso de voto democrático donde la comunidad identifica preguntas que duplican el contenido existente, son irrazonables para responder en su estado actual o no son apropiadas para este sitio.
>
> ¿Cuándo debería votar para cerrar una pregunta?
>
> Las preguntas deben ser cerradas emitiendo votos de cierre si:
>
> - Son suficientemente similares a preguntas ya existentes y se les respondería de manera idéntica.
> - Son poco claras, demasiado amplias o de algún modo hacen difícil identificar el problema de manera que pueda ser abordada por los contestatarios.
> - No están relacionadas a la temática del sitio, como se describe en el Centro de Ayuda.

No enlazaré aquí todo el texto del privilegio, pero nuevamente se observa que el texto alienta a usar el privilegio aunque exista la alternativa.

Un usuario con 3000 puntos de reputación, en cualquier sitio de la red de Stack Exchange, tendrá (o es lo que se espera) el criterio suficiente para detectar preguntas mal formuladas, fuera de tema e incluso *spam*.

Quien emite un voto de cierre lo hace en base a la experiencia previa. No se necesita añadir una sugerencia de dejar un comentario antes o después de emitir el voto de cierre. El comentario siempre será opcional y no obligatorio, excepto para los casos de preguntas duplicadas y de cierres por *otros motivos*, donde el comentario es añadido automáticamente por el sistema al emitir el voto.

No todas las preguntas se pueden clasificar dentro de uno de los motivos de cierre en particular, algunas clasifican a más de un motivo, por lo cual el motivo de cierre quedará siempre a discreción del usuario que se encuentre realizando las labores de moderación (ojo, que todos somos moderadores, no sólo los diamantados).

## ¿En qué ayuda la propuesta?

En mi opinión no ayuda en nada, al contrario distrae la atención del acto de sufragio. Todos los que tenemos el privilegio de emitir votos, de cualquier naturaleza, sabemos que existe la alternativa del comentario, pero también sabemos que los mismos no tienen la trascendencia ni la importancia del voto. El que se nos sugiera *pensar* en la alternativa antes de votar, como dije antes, desvirtúa el privilegio obtenido.

Además, el voto negativo o de cierre no es algo definitivo. Existen mecanismos para reabrir preguntas cerradas. Incluso existen medallas a preguntas que habiendo sido votadas en contra, son resucitadas con votos a favor.

Muchas veces has manifestado tu preocupación sobre lo que tu consideras un ambiente *no amigable* para con los usuarios nuevos que publican sus dudas. Manifiestas que sólo se les enlaza a documentación del sitio *poco clara* o *nada útil*, sin embargo no estoy de acuerdo en esto último.

Mis comentarios para usuarios nuevos siempre son del siguiente estilo, y muchos otros usuarios hacen más o menos lo mismo:

[image: Ejemplo de comentario a usuarios nuevos]

Si el OP se toma el tiempo de leer los enlaces sugeridos, encontrará cosas como estas:

> **Busca ayuda para preguntar por ayuda**
>
> A pesar de todos tus esfuerzos, puedes encontrar tus preguntas pobremente recibidas. ¡No te desesperes! Aprender a redactar una buena pregunta es una búsqueda digna, y no la vas a dominar tras una noche. Acá hay algunos recursos adicionales que puedes encontrar útiles:
>
> - Escribiendo la pregunta perfecta
> - ¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?
> - ¿Cómo redacto y respondo a preguntas sobre tareas?
> - ¿Cómo puedo depurar programas pequeños?
> - Meta discusiones sobre redactar preguntas
> - Cómo redactar preguntas de manera inteligente - extenso pero buen consejo.

O incluso esta otra perla:

> **Verificable**
>
> Para poder ayudar a solucionar tu problema, otros deberán saber que existe:
>
> - Describe el problema. “No me funciona“ no es una declaración útil. Dinos cuál debería ser el comportamiento esperado. Cuéntanos cual es la redacción exacta del error que se produce y en qué linea se está produciendo. Pon un resumen breve del problema en el título de tu pregunta.
> - Elimina todas las cuestiones no necesarias al problema. Si tu pregunta no es acerca de un error de compilación, asegúrate de que no haya errores de ese tipo. Usa un programa como JSLint para validar lenguajes interpretados. Todo el HTML y XML debe ser verificado.
> - ¡Asegúrate de que el ejemplo reporta el problema en la actualidad! Si solucionaste el problema inadvertidamente mientras preparas el aporte pero no lo pruebas de nuevo, sería bueno saberlo antes de pedir ayuda.
>   Para mas ayuda en como depurar tu programa para crear un ejemplo mínimo, [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) tiene un muy buen articulo de blog sobre este tema.

No todos leen completamente los artículos enlazados, no todos aplican lo que aprenden de los mismos, pero es innegable que los artículos son ricos y claros en su contenido.

Comment: no, estoy de acuerdo. por que el voto negativo carece de un objetivo especifico para el usuario .. como tu mismo lo dices ... ***la ayuda alienta a usarlo el voto negativo en caso extremos y no todas las publicaciones son casos extremos** ... dime algo, la policia en tu pais le dispara a cualquiera en calle cierto? ... que te den un arma y la decisión de usarla no es para que le dispares a todo el que comente un error ...

Comment: cuando un voto negativo tenga un costo de 20 puntos entonces comenzaran a dejar comentarios mas objetivo y menos genéricos ... por que como dices en tu ejemplo le das toda la biblia para lectura al usuario, cuando solo ha cometido un pecado ...

Comment: evalúa lo siguiente... y olvídate de la ayuda y de todo lo que conoces en la red de stack Exchange.... ¿Qué hace crecer una comunidad de calidad, la comunicación o los disparos?? piensa que cada vez que emites un voto negativo es el equivalente a que le dispares a alguien eso si la red fuera una guerra pero no lo es ... es un red de personas que necesitan comunicarse para entenderse.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con los votos negativos y estoy de acuerdo con los votos de cierre, pero no estoy de acuerdo con el uso que le dan las personas que lo pueden usar por que hay una idiosincracia de llenar todo de votos negativos y cerrar las preguntas... coartando el crecimiento de la comunidad... fijate quienes participan en meta los mismo de siempre... quiene participan en dar respuesta y comentar los mismos de siempre...

Comment: cual es el promedio de preguntas por usuario??? no llegan a 15 y el promedio de respuesta por usuario no llega a 15 tampoco ... por que el que llega al sitio despues de la primera pregunta sale corriendo...

Comment: no se cual es el objetivo de la comunidad ... pero no veo nada bueno de esto ...

Comment: No le veo lo malo a pedirle al usuario que dá un voto negativo que deje opcionalmente un comentario, siempre y cuando no sea obligatorio por mí esta bien. Pero esa es solo mi opinión.

Comment: Estupenda respuesta. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con lo que dices.

Comment: Entiendo que el voto negativo "es la herramienta principal de moderación del sitio". Sin embargo, más allá de eso no veo diferencia alguna con el dislike de Youtube. No aporta nada al OP un voto negativo más que "tu pregunta es de baja calidad". En mi opinion, dejar comentarios debería ser una prioridad. Y si el OP no reaccionó a los comentarios en mas o menos una semana, ahí es cuando va el voto negativo.

Comment: @DanteS el problema de obligar a dejar un comentario por cada voto negativo va atado a la garantía de voto anónimo. Al final mi derecho de voto anónimo priva sobre la obligatoriedad de dejar un comentario. Toma en cuenta que muchos no siempre tenemos tiempo para dejar un comentario, por mínimo que este sea. Obligar a dejarlo para votos negativos sería totalmente contraproducente, los usuarios simplemente no votarían negativo porque su voto no sería anónimo y muchas veces ni siquiera hace falta un comentario.

Comment: Yo nunca dije que dejar comentarios fuera obligatorio para votar negativo. A lo que me refiero es que debería ser un principio que la comunidad debería tomar en cuenta. En lugar de dejar un voto negativo, deja un comentario directamente sin votar negativo. Si no tienes tiempo de comentar, comenta despues, pero no votes negativo. Dime un ejemplo en el cual un voto negativo no requiere un comentario.

Comment: Por otro lado, pocos hacemos seguimiento a los comentarios dejados, sobre todo si no hay un feedback real del OP, por lo que preguntas mal formuladas quedarían sin votación negativa ya que se estaría esperando respuesta a los comentarios previos dejados. En mi caso, leo cerca de 50 preguntas o más al día, es muy difícil llevar un registro de todas las acciones en el poco tiempo que dedico a la moderación. Dicho esto, un voto negativo sigue siendo para mí y para muchos una medida más efectiva que llenar de comentarios una mala publicación. Saludos

Comment: Es ahí donde el sistema de revisión debería actuar y mostrar preguntas reportadas como baja calidad, con al menos un comentario que no es del op, que no haya habido comentarios del OP en más de una semana luego de una edición por parte del propio op. Además, no es mejor el sistema de votos de cierre? Cuando una pregunta es cerrada, el OP recibe feedback automatico, a diferencia del voto negativo que practicamente no da feedback.

Comment: Para mi, el sistema de votos de cierre debería ser la verdadera "herramienta principal de moderacion"

Comment: Pero es que son 2 acciones diferentes. Votar negativo es diferente a reportar. Cuando reportas una pregunta es por algún motivo particular que incluye, como no, la mala calidad de una pregunta. Usualmente se aplica a preguntas pésimamente redactadas que nunca podrán mejorarse. Aquí el problema es que si desvirtuamos el sistema de votos en favor de un sistema de comentarios, es muy probable que el sitio deje de tener contenido de calidad. Un *upvote* no es un *like*, y un *downvote* tampoco es un *dislike*, no traspolemos términos de las redes antisociales al sitio, ya que [es.so] no lo es.

Comment: Piensa que las preguntas abandonadas y con votos negativos, son automáticamente removidas por el sistema. En un sistema de comentarios, el sistema poco o nada podría hacer para realizar esa limpieza, ya que ¿cómo determina la calidad? ¿Por la cantidad de comentarios? ¿Analizando el contenido de los comentarios? Dejar comentario será siempre una decisión personal, igual que votar. Pero votar será siempre más efectivo y rápido que dejar un comentario. Al menos es como yo lo veo.

Answer (score 3):

Como dije en [Los 3 votos para el cierre causan un problema si no se dejan comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5167/83):

> El problema no es de los usuarios que votan para cerrar. El problema es de la plataforma
> (...)

> La plataforma debe mejorar en cuanto a fomentar calidad con pasos muy claros. Si no, estamos obligando a los usuarios con ganas a que repitan una y otra vez lo mismo a un sinnúmero de usuarios que se registran en el sitio sin que se les guíe.

Los votos positivos y negativos, así como los de cierre, tienen su finalidad. Yo si veo algo mal o cerrable, voto en consecuencia. Puedo dejar un comentario o no, pero la esencia es que así como está *ahora*, está mal. Mi forma de trabajar es REST, teniendo en cuenta toda la información existente en ese momento, y nada más. Condicionar un voto a cómo será después, o cómo pueda ser, no creo que ayude. Quién sabe si eso cambiará, si mejorará. Por eso, Stack Overflow también proporciona la posibilidad de retractar los votos: porque si la cosa cambia, puedes cambiar tu acción. Pero insisto, no creo un buen marco mental el condicionar una acción sobre una publicación a que el estado actual acabe cambiando.

Comment: no se esta condicionando una accion, la accion de voto de cierre sigue tal cual y la de voto negativo sigue tal cual, solo se busca mejorar un par de descripcionws buscando fomentar el uso de comentario y mejorar la comunicacion con el usuario., todo esto sigue siendo descicion de los usuarios.

Comment: como dices fomentar de manera corta... despues de un cierre y votos negativos, no has fomentado nada bueno... en alguien que como dices a lo mejor no ha leido ninguno de los articulos del sitio... tiene que ser una persona muy necesitada... para que intente averiguar por que recivio votos negativos... en pocas palabra un voto negativo solo ayuda a la estadistica de la plataforma... el cual es el objetivo real rankear post... no transmite conocimiento.